# Mysql error 10061 on Dual network

Tags: mysql, general-network-error

I have a redhat-linux machine where I have a mysql-server and this machine has been connected to two different network(dual network at a same time). While connecting to mysql-server from a remote machine for a particular user from one network it gets connected but while connecting from a another network it gets me a error code of 10061. IP-address has been configured for both the network and I have also restarted mysql-services and user has all the grant permission from the both the IP-addresses. But problem persist.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall on the other network may be blocking it.

Comment: no there is no issue of firewall.. if there was issue of it... it will not be connected through other network.

Comment: Use a packet sniffer to capture the traffic and see what's different with the two clients.

Answer (score 0):

The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on ' server ' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the one configured on the server.

Comment: He says he can connect from one client, but not a different client, so the server must be running.

Comment: Barmar you are right... mysql server is configured with predefined settings and running fine on a server.

Comment: when i ping the server. I get the response from it also.

Answer (score 0):

I got the access of database from both the network by making the changing in /etc/myconf.ini by making available to both the network.